# Why DmlException.getDmlFields return null for required fields?

Tags: dmlexception

I tried to write error handler to show errors near the fields that caused them. All works fine with every kind of Dml error except when required field is empty. How can I find field name from exception other then from `getDmlFields` method because it returns null in case of

> error with StatusCode = REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING?

Comment: Have you created  a field in VF and trying to capture this DmlException.getDmlFields() in controller?

Comment: No, it's lightning component in community, but it doesn't matter because DmlException.getMessage getting correct error message